# Autofill an HTML form

Tags: forms

What applications exist that can take a series of fields from my db (or csv output from my db) and insert them into a web-based form and then submit that form?

Big Picture Use Case:

I maintain an in-house registration management system for webinars that we produce/present. Currently we use GoToWebinar.com to host our events but they haven't always been (and may not always continue to be) our vendor.

GoToWebinars.com does not provide me an API for creating registrations for 3rd party individuals. So when someone decides to attend one of our events they have to fill out 2 registrations forms, mine and GoToWebinars.com. I'd like to automate the task of filling in GoToWebinar's registration form.

Comment: Any prefer programming language?

Comment: I'm working in .net but would kinda prefer a scripted solution as opposed to baking something into an assembly.

Comment: Hi Steve, I'm working on a browser extension that does just this. Gonna send you a message. Would be super curious to see if it addresses your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am looking into the same thing. I found some bits and pieces here and there and was able to decipher the URL to post to GTW:

https://www.gotowebinar.com/en_US/island/webinar/registration.flow?Template=island/webinar/registration.tmpl&Form=webinarRegistrationForm&WebinarKey=XXX_YOUR_WEBINAR_ID_XXX&Name_First=ViewersFirstName&Name_Last=ViewersLastName&Email=ViewersEmailAddress

If you are using cURL, then be sure to use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION because there are some redirections on the GTW side and cURL needs to follow them.

So far this seems to work for us.

Good luck!

Comment: I also found some code that appears to post to a similar URL.  For the life of me I can't find any documentation on it though!!!  FYI, I also had the additional parameters for "PhoneNumber" and "Organization".

Comment: I also have an open question specifically for the location of the API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600926/where-are-the-gotomeeting-and-gotowebinar-api-web-services

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but let me offer a way to [call the CITRIX API via PHP to register a new GotoWebinar attendee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298477/register-user-through-api-to-gotowebinar/29083396#29083396), in case somebody else hits this page looking for the answer to your question.

Comment: GTW has made great strides since the OP - the API is generally a pleasure to work against with recent updates. Still some maddening holes but they move in the right direction.

Comment: @justSteve: Hmmm, it must have been REALLY bad in the past, considering it's not terribly clear now.